# google analytics apiで特定URLのpv数などを取得

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

google apiで特定URLのリストがあり、それぞれのURLのpv数などを取得したいのですが、
良い方法はありますでしょうか？

```
filters='ga:pagepath==list'
```

のイメージですが、うまくいきません。

Answer (score 1):

"==list" の部分が具体的にどうなってるのか、よくわかりませんが、 filtersには正規表現が、使えるのでそれで取得するのはどうでしょうか。

例えば、以下のようなURLのパスのリストがあるとします。

```
/hoge/index.html
/hoge/fuga/index.html
/hoge/fuga2/index.html
```

この全てのパスのデータを取得したければ、下記のように書くことができます。 /hoge以下の全てのURLのデータを取得するという意味です。

```
filters='ga:pagepath=~/hoge/*'
```

詳しくは下記のリンクを参考にしてみてください。

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filterSyntax
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245132/google-analytics-api-filter-by-uri

Comment: /hoge/以下に、取得したURLと取得したくないURLがあるので、~=ですと、いらいないものが含まれてしまいますので、特定のURLをリストで与えられないか考えた次第です。説明不足ですいません。